# Deploying multiple micro-services on 1 cloud server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, server, cloud

I have a few (python) microservices which serve as the backend of my web application.
I'm willing to deploy the microservices to some cloud platform (either AWS, Azure, etc).

Should I create 1 VM and deploy all the microservices on the same server, with different ports? If I should create 1 VM for each microservice, should they speak with each other through public IP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The short direct answer for you is YES. You can do that, directly to deploy all microservices on one VM using different ports is feasible. And you can set different public ports for a public IP in the NSG of networking setting on Azure VM.

However, it's not make sense and break the microservice architecture. But per my experience, you can try to use Nginx as reverse proxy or use Docker (even with Kubernetes) to manage yours microservices on a VM in the development or testing stage.

1. To use Nginx as reverse proxy to expose the same port with different request path to access the backend microservices with different ports. It will help to reduce the cost of migration in future.
2. Recommended. To use Docker with Kubernetes to deploy different microservices images like using different VMs. These microservices insider container bind the same port, and expose different ports outsider container. Then, to use Nginx as reverse proxy for these containers, too. In future, it will help to migrate them to Azure Kubernetes cluster easily, and get better price than VM.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Creating 1 server would kill the purpose for microservices. Services are deployed across 
multiple nodes(servers) , more specifically multiple AZs (availability zones)

It also depends if you have stand alone services deployed directly using code behind server or are you using containers ? Because both will have different approaches to deploy and maintain.

Answer (score -1):

As have said @Imran Arshad Deploy some microservice in one server is a bad idea.
If you are in starting phase of a project, you can use the ECS service of AWS with 1-2 ec2 instances. In this way, you can have HA at a low cost.